# Assigning a locked variable in an R package

Tags: r, package, constants

I'm trying to assign Pascal-Case versions of the variables true, false, na and null into my R package. This is very easy to do, but I also want to lock the binding to prevent renaming of the variable.

```
# An anti-example from the base libraries
F <- TRUE
T <- FALSE

T && T
FALSE
```

I can't figure out how to lock a variable in a  package to prevent further modification. The follow mock package doesn't work

```
# test.R
True <- TRUE
lockBinding('True', environment())

#DESCRIPTION
Collate:
    'test.R'
```

When running R CMD check I get the following error:

```
Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : 
    cannot change value of locked binding for 'True'
```

What is the correct way of locking an R package variable so it can't be re-assigned?

edit: included the wrong error message.

Comment: You are not telling us the whole story. The token `Na` is not reserved in R, so you must have created it or attempted to access it when it was not in existence ... or something. The error mesasage does not refer to 'True' (also not a reserved word in R.)

Comment: FWIW, once the package is loaded the binding is locked anyway, so you're only going to prevent code that is inside the package from modifying the binding during initial installation and loading. Is that really your goal?

Comment: @MartinMorgan I'm not sure that's true. For example, require(plyr); llply <- identity; llply(10) == 10

Comment: @IShouldBuyABoat given the error message I'm getting I would tend to agree (fixed the message by the way); the error is very strange. I didn't assign the variable elsewhere, and it's the first function in the collate field, so if there's a detail I'm leaving out I'm unsure what it is.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Mostly not answering your question. I agree with @IShouldByABoat that there's more going on, a package with the simple structure you indicate doesn't generate the error you see for me. Likely you're trying to modify True elsewhere in your code (!) or perhaps you've got some cruft in your .Rprofile or .RData file that is interfering -- run your check as `R --vanilla CMD check`.

Functions and symbols are defined in a package name space, for instance

```
library(plyr)             ## load package name space, attach to the search() path
getNamespace(plyr)        ## package name space
ls(getNamespace(plyr))    ## symbols defined in the name space
plyr::llply               ## definition of `llply` in the name space
```

The package name space is locked after it has been loaded

```
assign("llply", identity, envir=getNamespace("plyr"))
## Error in assign("llply", identity, envir = getNamespace("plyr")) : 
##   cannot change value of locked binding for 'llply'
```

Assigning to a similarly named variable at the command line creates a new variable in the `.GlobalEnv` (the first location on the search() path) rather than modifying the variable in the package name space

```
ls()               ## no symbol 'llply' in .GlobalEnv
llply <- identity  ## new symbol 'llply' in .GlobalEnv
llply(10)          ## use first llply function in search(), i.e., in .GlobalEnv
plyr::llply(10)    ## circumvent search path and use llply from plyr name space
```

So code such as

```
True <- TRUE
lockBinding("True", environment())
```

only adds a locked binding from the time True is created until the package is loaded; after that the binding is locked anyway.

Maybe you want to create a variable True in the user's .GlobalEnv, and make that so that it cannot be changed. This has to be done when the package is load'ed (or attach'ed), when the user's current .GlobalEnv is visible, with something like

```
.onAttach <- function(...) {
    assign("True", TRUE, .GlobalEnv)
    lockBinding("True", .GlobalEnv)
}
```

This only locks the binding in the .GlobalEnv so it cannot be changed, but does not stop the user from removing it (e.g., using `rm("True")`). Messing with your user's .GlobalEnv will likely also serve to irritate your user more than further your programming agenda.

Comment: +1 for post, would like to add +10 for last sentence but can't.